# Dynamically change navigation bar color for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, navigationbar

I have multiple pages for each prototype cell in my ios app. I want the navigation bar color to change with each page. Here is the code I tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = workout.color
        self.detailText.text = workout.workoutText
        self.title = workout.title


        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = workout.color


        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = workout.color

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```

The color changes for the frst click but then remains the same no matter which page I click on even though the title, text and background color change correctly. If everything else changes, why doesn't the navigation bar color change?

Comment: Try to set navigationBar color in viewWillAppear(), each time view controller's view will be displayed it will update navigation bar color.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't make a difference:
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = workout.color
      
    }

Comment: are you sure you're not doing anything else this navigationBar ? Your code seems fine

Comment: Seems like `self.navigationController? = nil`. How are you transition to new view controllers?

Comment: The suggestions didn't work so I simply made my navigation bar transparent and now it takes up the background color of the page. Thanks though!